# how to write array columns into CSV file in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have been trying to read parquet file which has the array columns and write it into csv file for specific IDs. I have flattened the array columns and trying to write the data into csv file. I am getting the below error while writing.

error - **An error occurred while calling o271.showString. optional int64 images_variant_ids is not a group**

column : |-- image_variant_ids: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

````
df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option('dropFieldIfAllNull', True).load("s3 path")
# flattening of array columns
while True:
    columns = []
    for name, type in df.dtypes:
        if type[:5] == "array":
            columns.append(name)
    df = df.withColumn("arr_col", arrays_zip(*columns))
    df = df.withColumn("arr_col", explode_outer(col("arr_col")))
    for column in columns:
        df = df.withColumn(column, col("arr_col." + column))
    df = df.drop(col('arr_col'))
    if len(columns) > 0:
        pass
    else:
        break

df = df.filter(df.id.isin(['6581755216010', '6641403232394', '6581768192138', '6798057406602']))

df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("s3 path")```
````

Error:
2022-07-04 14:01:37,065 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/shopify_data", line 51, in 
df1.distinct().show(truncate=False)
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 487, in show
print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in **call**
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o273.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 16) (172.35.226.227 executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: optional int64 images_variant_ids is not a group